# ¿Como hacer que funcione el lazy loading de un datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

actualmente uso una librería para hacer mi datatable, que me da muchas opciones para conffigurar mi tabla y a lo que tengo entendido una de ellas es la opcion de recarga por necesidad, esto quiere decir que cargara mis datos de la bd conforme me vaya moviendo en la tabla y a lo cual tengo entendido se llama lazy loading.

Esta es la forma en que configure mi tabla:

```
$('#MainContent_tabla').DataTable({
                columns: [
{ title: "Nombre" },
{ title: "Vehiculo" },
{ title: "Fecha de Lectura" },
{ title: "Fecha de Salida" },
{ title: "Id del Usuario" },
{ title: "Imagen" }
                ],
                "language": {
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Registros por pagina",
                "zeroRecords": "No hay ningun registro que coincida",
                "info": "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
                "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)",
                "search": "Buscar Palabra:",
                "paginate": {
                    "previous": "Siguiente",
                    "next": "Anterior"
                },
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": "ConsultarEvidencia.aspx.cs",
                "deferLoading": 57
            }
            });
```

Las ultimas 4 lineas son para la opción del loading lento.
Dentro de la clase que se llama en ajax solo hay un metodo que es el siguiente:

```
 public void btnOk_T_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        HistoryBI historyBi=new HistoryBI();

        Inicio = dtInicio.Text;
        Fin = dtFin.Text;

        data = historyBi.ConsultarEvidencia(Inicio,Fin);


        //DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Ned-Design\Documents\projects\NederaV4\Administrators\Temp");//Assuming Test is your Folder
        //FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.png"); //Getting Text files



        foreach (DataRow dtRow in data.Rows)
        {

            TableRow row = new TableRow();

            for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
            {
                TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
                cell1.Text = dtRow[i].ToString();
                row.Cells.Add(cell1);
            }

            tabla.Rows.Add(row);

        }



    }
```

Comment: por favor aclárame que significa "conforme me vaya moviendo en la tabla" ya que yo también utilizo datatables y la información que muestran mis tablas es dinamica, por ejemplo, el usuario puede reordenar la tabla por cualquiera de sus campos al igual que utilizar la barra de search para actualizar los registros asociados al campo de busqueda. Todo esto lo logro sin utilizar ninguna de las 4 líneas que mencionas, es decir, sin lazyloading. Por eso te pregunto nuevamente a que te refieres con "conforme me vaya moviendo en la tabla" podrías describirlo mejor? por favor

Comment: Generalmente lazyloading se utiliza en grandes proyectos para evitar ciertos "cuellos de botella" originados por inmensa cantidad de información proveniente de la base de datos por lo que en la mayoría de los casos (proyectos pequeños-medianos) no es necesario su uso. Ahora si verdaderamente es lo que buscas revisa la siguiente [explicación](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316220/lazy-loading-of-table-rows-in-jquery-datatables-1-10-10). Pero te recuerdo lazyloading es utilizado para cantidades importantes de información para lo demás el uso estándar de las datatables es suficiente

Comment: @Huskie con eso me refería a que la datatable se llenara solo con los 30 registros que se visualizaban en ese momento y que no cargara toda la información de golpe y conforme se vaya moviendo en el paginador de un lado a otro, se fueran cargando solo los registros que se quieran ver de la bd sin necesidad que en la carga inicial se traiga toda la info de golpe, espero haber si claro. Gracias por comentar

Comment: @Huskie si el proyecto en el que estoy es una empresa de desarrollo de software con cantidades importantes de información.

Comment: Ok. Por favor chequea el link que anexé en el comentario que hice anterior a este allí encontrarás una forma muy sencilla de utilizar lazyloading que probablemente te sirva de solución. Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que las opciones de

```
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "ConsultarEvidencia.aspx.cs",
    "deferLoading": 57
```

estan dentro de languages. si sacas las opciones a otro corchete mas deberia de funcionar.

```
        "language": {
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Registros por pagina",
        "zeroRecords": "No hay ningun registro que coincida",
        "info": "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
        "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
        "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)",
        "search": "Buscar Palabra:",
        "paginate": {
            "previous": "Siguiente",
            "next": "Anterior"
        },
    },
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "ConsultarEvidencia.aspx.cs",
        "deferLoading": 57
```